# How to export SSRS report directly to csv without rendering

Tags: sql-server, csv, reporting-services

I have very large rdl report, about 50 columns and 500,000 rows. The SQL procedure that lies behind the report is just ordinary select * from table.  It takes just a few seconds to execute.  However, when I want to render that report in SSRS, it takes too long.

The end user wants just to export that report in csv.  He doesn't need SSRS to render the report.  Is there a way to set up default render mode of the report to csv.  Then, when the user runs it, the report will automatically ask him to save in .csv, without rendering?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Easiest is to use URL Access, specifying `&rs:command=render&rs:format=csv`

Another method is to use the API - I guess it depends on what you are most comfortable with.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152835.aspx

Comment: [In case the MSDN redirect stops working.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/url-access-parameter-reference)

Answer (score -2):

You can use LocalReport.Render method to get bytes[] from report in page load directly and then export it as csv:

```
Warning[] warnings;
string[] streamids;
string mimeType;
string encoding;
string filenameExtension;

this.ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
        this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = 
           @"c:\Reports\Report1.rdl";
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(
           new ReportDataSource("Test", LoadSalesData()));


byte[] bytes = reportViewer.LocalReport.Render(
    "CSV", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out filenameExtension,
    out streamids, out warnings);

Response.Buffer = true;
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = mimeType;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName + ".csv");
Response.BinaryWrite(bytes); // create the file
Response.Flush();
```

Comment: exception on LocalReport.Render() : "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.\r\nParameter name: format", i think csv is not supported here.

Comment: I am looking for the same answer, LocalReport.Render with CS is not supported i've found.. we are migrating from RDL using SSRS where the same call method does support CSv - not in a localreport i have found.